# Can only ping hostname but not a domain

Tags: dns, active-directory

Ubuntu Gnome 13.10

What I can do:

- `ping hostnameX`

  - Response: `PING hostnameX.domain.local (10.0.0.1)`
- `nslookup hostnameX`

  - Response: `Name: hostnameX.domain.local; Address: 10.0.0.1`
  - Response coming from: `Server: 127.0.1.1; Address: 127.0.1.1`
- `nslookup hostnameX.domain.local`

  - Response: `Name: hostnameX.domain.local; Address: 10.0.0.1`
  - Response coming from: `Server: 127.0.1.1; Address: 127.0.1.1`

What I CANNOT do:

- `ping hostnameX.domain.local`

  - Response: `ping: unknown host hostnameX.domain.local`

This happens with all hostnames within the domain

This is my /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search domain.local
```

I already tried the same with dnsmasq disabled, without success...

UPDATE: I also tried some other distros (debian and opensuse), and they all have the same problem. So it looks to me as a general network problem, but what exactly...

Any clues?

Comment: so when your nslookups succeed, do they indicate your that the nameserver responding to the query is the one running on 127.0.1.1?

Comment: @FrankThomas I added this to my question

Comment: What does your domain.local zone look like?

Comment: @NickW do you mean on the dns server? I don't have access to the server unfortunately

Comment: If 127.0.0.1 is serving domain.local, you should have access to it?

Comment: @NickW no that IP is my localhost, which is serving dnsmasq...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to join the windows domain with LikeWise, I found a note [on this page in the troubleshooting section](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/likewise-open.html), which states to **remove 'mdns4' entry from the 'hosts:' part in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` when trying to join an AD domain with a .local syntax**.
I did this and suddenly I could ping (and therefore also access) FQDNs within the .local domain ...

A [second source](http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2011/09/fix-linux-dns-issues-with-local.html)  is describing the same problem and sollution